# Detecting a USB keyboard with pyudev?

Tags: python, keyboard, udev, pyudev

I've been picking through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410462/set-keyboard-layout-using-pyudev) to try to detect a hotplug of a USB keyboard, but ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD isn't a key in the udev Device object that represents my keyboard.

How can I use pyudev to detect whether or not the hotplugged device is a keyboard?